# Grails: does belongsTo create a new column for a back reference?

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

My code looks something like

```
class Person {
    Nose nose
}

class Nose {
    static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

This is supposed to create a foreign key column for Nose on the 'person' table and also a back reference column for Person on the 'nose' table right?

There is no column generated for the back reference on the 'nose' table for me right now and I was wondering if this is normal...

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html
(Seems like this is what the documentation is saying, but I'm thinking I'm interpreting it wrong)

edit:
i edited the code snippet because i wrote the wrong thing down (haven't had coffee today)

Comment: Is the missing equals sign in `belongsTo [nose:Nose]` a typo (it should be `belongsTo = [nose: Nose]`)? Ditto for missing `static`?

Comment: my bad, yeah i have belongsTo = [nose:Nose] in my actual code. i'll fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the Person in the Nose, not Nose itself, like this:

```
class Person {
    Nose nose
}

class Nose {
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENT: ah, I see.  Now that I am reading your question again, were you expecting to have both a `person_id` column in `Nose` and `nose_id` column in `Person`? Because that will never happen in GORM, at least not automatically - for your schema, only the `Person` table will contain a `nose_id` column per documentation.

Comment: i wrote the wrong thing twice, sorry about that. i have static belongsTo = [person: Person]

Answer (score 0):

In grails we use `belongsTo` for cascading purpose,You should use

```
class Nose {
belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

and yes in case of `belongsTo` a back reference will be stored in **Nose** having the `person_id`.

Comment: sorry abdullah, i had multiple typos in my question. i had static belongsTo = [person: Person]

Comment: Do you getting abnormal result in this case, if yes than what?

Comment: no errors at least. when i assign an instance of Person to an instance of nose and save, i get no errors, but when i fetch that instance from the database, person_id is set to null. i also see that there is no column for person_id (the back reference) on the nose table.

Comment: Is `person_id` a typo? I think you should be able to get `Person` object via `nose.person` and this object ID via `nose.personId`.

Comment: @MarcinŚwierczyński i was using SQL queries in my terminal (hence person_id), my main question is whether or not a dedicated column is created for the back reference by grails/gorm.

Comment: Like I wrote in the other answer, no. Only one reference is created and that is `person->nose`. If you would like to have it the other way, i.e. `person<-nose` that can be arranged, too - but not `Person<->Nose`, at least not by convention.